# how to fix "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'x' "?

Tags: python, spyder, attributeerror

I want to see a very simple plot. But I get an error for 'x' in 'def'. Please let me know why.

Python 2.7 / spyder

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import math

def func(x,a,b,): 
    return a*np.x+b

x=np.linspace(-1,1,100)
y=func(x,1,1)
plt.plot(x,y,linewidth=3, color='red')
plt.show()
```

Output I receive is :

```
  runfile('I:/K/python/least square_HW.py', wdir='I:/K/python') Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-19-c03c1aa079d4>", line 1, in <module> runfile('I:/K/python/least square_HW.py', wdir='I:/K/python')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 704, in runfile execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 93, in execfile exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "I:/K/python/least square_HW.py", line 18, in <module> y=func(x,1,1)
  File "I:/K/python/least square_HW.py", line 14, in func return a*np.x+b
        AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'x'
```

Comment: correct this `a*np.x+b` , what is x doing, its not a method of numpy

Comment: What does `a*np.x+b` mean? The `numpy` module does not have an attribute `x`. Did you intend to write `a*x + b`?

Comment: OMG... Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3):

Numpy does not have any 'x'. The dot operator is used to call function of that class. I think you are trying `return a*x+b`.

Comment: @user10833409 no problems... :) if you found the answer to be helpful, then please mark it as correct by clicking on the tickmark on the left of the answer. Thanks.